# Bare metal spinlock implementation in rust

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, arm, bare-metal, spinlock

I am working on bare metal programming in rust on a Raspberry Pi 3 running in 64 bit mode. I have implemented a spinlock as follows:

```
use core::{sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering}, cell::UnsafeCell, ops::{Deref, DerefMut}};

pub struct SpinMutex<T> {
    lock: AtomicBool,
    data: UnsafeCell<T>
}

impl<T> SpinMutex<T> {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    pub const fn new(data: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            lock: AtomicBool::new(false),
            data: UnsafeCell::new(data)
        }
    }

    pub fn lock(&self) -> SpinMutexGuard<T> {
        while self.lock.compare_exchange(false, true, Ordering::Acquire, Ordering::Relaxed).is_err() {}

        SpinMutexGuard {
            lock: &self.lock,
            data: unsafe { &mut *self.data.get() }
        }
    }
}

unsafe impl<T> Sync for SpinMutex<T> {}

pub struct SpinMutexGuard<'a, T> {
    lock: &'a AtomicBool,
    data: &'a mut T
}

impl<'a, T> Deref for SpinMutexGuard<'a, T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        self.data
    }
}

impl<'a, T> DerefMut for SpinMutexGuard<'a, T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        self.data
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Drop for SpinMutexGuard<'a, T> {
    /// The dropping of the MutexGuard will release the lock it was created from.
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.lock.store(false, Ordering::Release);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{SpinMutex};

    #[test]
    fn test_spin_mutex() {
        let state = SpinMutex::new(0);

        assert_eq!(*state.lock().data, 0);

        *state.lock().data = 9;

        assert_eq!(*state.lock().data, 9);
    }
}
```

When I run the tests on my local machine (64 bit windows) the locks works. However, on the Raspberry Pi the `lock` method gets stuck in an infinite loop and never returns. Is there a reason why this happens?

Here is how Rust compiles `compare_exchange_weak` with inlining disabled:

```
   80ba8:   9100400a    add x10, x0, #0x10
   80bac:   085f7d48    ldxrb   w8, [x10]
   80bb0:   34000068    cbz w8, 80bbc
   80bb4:   d5033f5f    clrex
   80bb8:   14000004    b   80bc8
   80bbc:   52800029    mov w9, #0x1                    // #1
   80bc0:   080b7d49    stxrb   w11, w9, [x10]
   80bc4:   3400004b    cbz w11, 80bcc
   80bc8:   2a1f03e9    mov w9, wzr
   80bcc:   7100011f    cmp w8, #0x0
   80bd0:   52000120    eor w0, w9, #0x1
   80bd4:   1a9f07e1    cset    w1, ne  /
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your spin lock, this is a lot of work. Have you thought of using something else or an approach where you don't have to worry about spin locks? I know it's not the question you're asking, but if I had to worry about spin locks I'd never get anything done.

Comment: Does changing all the orderings to `Ordering::SeqCst` accomplish anything?

Comment: My old Raspberry Pi only has one core. Probably more modern ones are multicore, but you are bare metal, so maybe you are not doing proper multitasking? Because I think that a spinlock with just one core makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have enough debugging infrastructure in place to be able to cause a trap while your lock is stuck, and inspect the state of the machine?  Also, I presume that you're already able to successfully run other Rust code on the bare metal, so that it's not a generic setup problem?

Comment: You said you were targeting `bare metal`, does that mean your RPi does not have a kernel which preempts your currently running thread? If so, the `compare_exchange` will spin forever because no other thread can run in case the lock is held by another thread. You'll need to put a call to `std::thread::yield_now()` into the loop to fix that. Also, unrelated to your problem, you might want to use `compare_exchange_weak` because you are no evaluating the original value in case `compare_exchange` fails.

Comment: But the test should still work, because here the lock is just locked and unlocked repeatedly in that order; there is never contention.

Comment: @DanChase I want to have a spin lock to be able to safely use mutable statics from multiple threads.

Comment: @Aplet123 that doesn't help

Comment: @rodrigo: The RPi 3B+ has 4 cores.

Comment: But you are using bare-metal so no OS, are you sure you are actually using all the cores?

Comment: @NateEldredge It seems that the problem is that the `compare_exchange_weak` method does not return. I'll try to get the disassembly of it

Comment: @NateEldredge I've added the compiled `compare_exchange_weak` function.

Comment: @rodrigo I am currently using a single core, however I want to be able to use multiple cores in the future

Comment: when you try a simple ldr/str exclusive test what do you see on this platform? (getting rid of all the other code)

Comment: isolate the problem by dividing it in half or fractions and then put it back together when the parts work.

Comment: You are bare metal and haven't enabled caches nor MMU?  So `ldxrb` will always fail as the exclusive lock can never be taken.

Comment: @artlessnoise ok. That makes sense. Time to enable the cache and MMU!

Comment: If you are scheduling, you also need to implement a `clrex` during a context switch so that one 'task/thread' does not confuse having a lock from another 'task/thread' that happens during a context switch.  It would be the same if you test with co-routines... but I don't think [tag:rust] has them.

Comment: Did caches and MMU help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-exhaustive list of conditions that I'm certain (I've tested them both ways) need to occur in order for atomics to work on RPi 4 aarch64 in `EL1` (ARMv8).
This will probably be very similar to RPi 3 (ARMv7).

- MMU must be enabled (`SCTLR_EL1` bit [0] set to `0b1`)
- Data caching must be enabled (`SCTLR_EL1` bit [2] set to `0b1`)
- The page on which the lock resides has to be marked as normal, cachable memory via `MAIR` (I've used `0xff` - I'm not sure which bits are redundant wrt. atomics, but I don't think there's much reason to use anything else for normal memory).